# Passing Id To PartialView That's in Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a table that lists users. I have a details link on last column. Link opens a modal that calls partial view. I used a static id (JohnSmith) and it works with below code.

Table row:

```
<td>
    <a data-target="#modalDetay" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.UserName">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Details</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Modal at the bottom of page:

```
<div id="modalDetay" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.Action("PartialDetay", "ActiveDirectory", new { id = "JohnSmith" })
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn blue">Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pass -row- data-id to id in @Html.Action. How can i do that?

Btw, i read lots of similar question but all answers include Jquery. I'm asking similar but looking for different answer. Isn't it possible without Jquery?

Comment: You could use a ViewModel class to achieve this and pass it along to your partial view. There a lot of examples in stackoverflow that show how to do this

Comment: If its something that can be computed when requesting the page you can pass it in with `@` and then the variable name, but if it is dynamic you will have to compute it using jQuery.  HTML.Action is computed when requesting the page so it actually puts the action there.  If you have the id replace "john smith" with `@id` if you don't then just replace `@html.Action` with and anchor tag and get the id using jquery

Comment: The Html.Partial call is executed at view rendering-time so you cannot dynamically pass HTML element attribute values. You have to fetch the view via ajax, and pass the appropriate parameters from client-sied. The reason why you see jQuery a lot is because AJAX is much more simple with using jQuery.

Comment: Should i change link section or just @Html.Action part?

Comment: But PartialView is another View. Does not it render after when i click Html.Action?